# Undefined reference to gets_s

Tags: c, string, gets

So basically I'm learning C and they taught us to use the gets() function, which I found that it was removed and cannot be used anymore. So I'm trying to learn to use the alternative, the gets_s() function, but I can't seem to. For example the following code gives me "Undefined reference to gets_s" when attempting to compile.:

```
char line[21];
gets_s( line, 20 );
printf( "The line entered was: %s\n", line );
```

A lot of people have said to use fgets() instead of gets() but I don't understand how that will work, since I want to read the user's input, not from a file.

Comment: You need to include a header than defines `gets_s`.

Comment: `gets_s` is only available in MSVC. Use `fgets`.

Comment: Even better, use `getline` if your system has it (like in recent Posix spec). It is dynamically allocating the buffer for the line, so can accept very large lines (if system resources permit them).

Comment: @ user Thanks. fgets wonderfully now.
@ Basile I'm still really a newb at programming and all so I dont really understand what buffer is, but I will be looking up getline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `gets_s` is not a first-class standard function. It is implemented by Visual Studio ([mentioned on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7.aspx)) where it is available if you include `stdio.h`.

Interestingly C11 introduces it as a somewhat standard function by mentioning it in Appendix K, "*Bounds-Checking interfaces*" along with other `_s` functions. However many compilers have chosen not to implement this interface so it is probably best not to rely on it.

To reiterate what user3121023 said, `fgets` is probably the safest way to go (but you should use `sizeof` if you can):

```
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
```

Note you **don't need to pass the one less than the size** of the array.

Comment: Wouldn't "(len) + 1" potentially cause write of "0" past the allocated memory? @ColeTobin